JPackage-result installed - how to add system properties?
I already have a Java Swing application, and it gets packaged using JPackage for Linux, Mac and Windows. That means I have native installers for the application.
Now there are users who need to run the application with additional system properties. For example FlatLAF can be customized like this - see https://www.formdev.com/flatlaf/system-properties/
So the question is: After a jpackage packaged installer has executed, what can a user do to run the application with specific system properties?

Assuming none of the custom-set system properties need to be specified at launch, then perhaps specifying a properties file with a command line argument or environment variable (and processing it at the start of the application, e.g., in main) is an option.

I found a solution that does not require any change to the application and thus can be done by users.

Note the properties file can also be done by users. It does not require the user to modify the application itself, though it will require a developer to modify the application to add the functionality.

Since JDK19 jpackage supports override location of cfg files. You don't need to edit the installation directories which risks being overwritten on next install. However you do have the problem that the next installation might add changes that your users need to copy to their override cfg file.
See JDK-8287060 Allow per-user and system wide configuration of a jpackaged app
For example on Windows you would copy and edit the config to here:
%LOCALAPPDATA%\YourAppName\LauncherName.cfg


I like this approach. Currently my application still gets bundled with JDK 17.

It should work if you make your JDK17 runtime with JDK17 jlink and use JDK19 jpackage --runtime-image your-jre17, so that jpackage isn't implicitly doing its own jlink step.

I like this solution, but it does not seem to be documented by either the user's guide or the tool guide. Either that or I'm blind and simply missed where this was mentioned.

@Slaw You are right, I don't think those guides have been updated much. I only stumbled on this change when looking at a recent regression which got backported to early updates of JDK17/21/22 and ruins things if you launch sub-processes.

The application is packaged using JPackage which automatically wraps Java applications into an easy to distribute executable. So there is no command line to set system properties on. Instead there is a configuration file.
This configuration file resides in either one of
$APPLICATION_HOME/app/<APPLICATION>.cfg
$APPLICATION_HOME/lib/app/<APPLICATION>.cfg.

On Linux this defaults to
/opt/<APPLICATION>/lib/app/<APPLICATION>.cfg

on Windows search for
C:\Program Files\<APPLICATION>\app\<APPLICATION>.cfg

Once you found the file, inside you will see a section called JavaOptions.
You can add more system properties, each one as a new line like so:
[JavaOptions]
java-options=-Djpackage.app-version=0.1-29
java-options=-Dflatlaf.uiScale=2.5

The example shows how to scale the fonts used by FlatLAF in case you have a high resolution screen.

One thing to be cautious about with this approach is that the *.cfg file is likely to be overwritten when the user upgrades the application. Or at least, I don't see why it would not be overwritten. This will force the user to set all the appropriate system properties again. The properties file approach I suggested does not have that problem.

I will more likely go for an updated JDK than implement configuration into each and every application. Furthermore, settings like heap size cannot be covered once the JVM is running.
